# Sequential test execution jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I want to run 2 day test and I am making use of Thread Group Start time and end time feature.

I am looking for design as shown below :

```
Thread Group 1 (First day start and end time with date)
--> HTTP Request 1 (Execute for 30 minutes)
--> HTTP Request 2 (Should start after 30 minutes i.e. after first one is terminated)
--> HTTP Request 3 (Should start after 60 minutes i.e. after second one is terminated)
Thread Group 1 (Second day start and end time with date)
--> HTTP Request 1 (Execute for 30 minutes)
--> HTTP Request 2 (Should start after 30 minutes i.e. after first one is terminated)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thread Group start and end times are **absolute**, therefore you will be able to execute the test only once without editing it. I would rather recommend sticking to relative times like:

- Thread Group, 2 loops

  - [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) configured to run for 1800 seconds

    - HTTP Request 1
  - Runtime Controller configured to run for 1800 seconds

    - HTTP Request 2
  - Runtime Controller configured to run for 1800 seconds

    - HTTP Request 3
  - [Flow Control Action](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-easily-implement-pacing-jmeter/) sampler configured to pause current thread for 86400000 milliseconds (24 hours)

    [image]

Comment: but I am also interested in executing HTTP Request 1,2 and 3 at different time. Like Request 1 to run for 30 min and then after 30 min request 2 should start and so on

Comment: Just put another copy of HTTP Request 1 under the 2nd Runtime Controller (or even better [use Module Controller to avoid code duplication](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller))

Comment: but runtime Controller controls how long its children will run. Controller will run its children until configured Runtime(s) is exceeded. By using this all my request will be executed at once and for 30min. Instead I want that my first request should start at for e.g. 9.00 AM, second @ 9.30 AM and so on